# IOS Parse Homescreen when currentUser() != nil

Tags: ios, swift, parsing, parse-platform

I am struggling with this (seems pretty straightforward), but I think it might be because my login/signup VCs are in a navigation controller, and the rest of my app (Homescreen etc) is in a separate TabBarController.

My "Is Initial VC" is set to the navigation controller that holds my Signup and Login VCs, and this launches and works perfectly, I am able to log in and I go to my HomeVC like so:

```
func transitionToHome() {
    let homeViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.Storyboard.homeViewController)
    view.window?.rootViewController = homeViewController
    view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Inside of my AppDelegate I have the following code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    setupParse()

    if  PFUser.current() != nil {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let homeVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.Storyboard.homeViewController)
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        self.window?.rootViewController?.present(homeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    return true
}
```

I have tried it backwards as well(Home TabbarVC is Initial, and in app delegate if Pf.current() == nil, launch with login), and made sure PFUser.current() was set to nil after logging out and it was, but it still was not working for me. I have read through other similar questions but I think my problem might be the tab bar vs navigation - or something with the use of windows. Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your code inside of SceneDelegate and you need to change it a bit:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

    if  PFUser.current() != nil {
        window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let homeVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.Storyboard.homeViewController)
        window?.rootViewController = homeVC
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey just one more thing. Now my app is launching to a black screen, I have tried to debug this and read through many answers. I am not sure what the issue is, might i need to add something in my info.plist? When I comment the code out from the SceneDelegate, then the app shows the login screen and works fine, but otherwise I just get sent to a black screen after my launch screen. Not sure what changed. (I did renew my apple developer account but dont think that matters)

Comment: I've edited my answer. You only want to assign a value to window if you are programmatically setting rootViewController. So, in short, I moved the `window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)` statement inside the if block.

Comment: Thank you sir. Got it, don't assign a value to window unless programmatically instantiating a rootviewcontroller.